# How to remove Response Class in Swaggger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am new to a swagger. I wrote the following code for response:

```
 "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "success",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/test1"
        }
      },
      "401": {
        "description": "error",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/test2"
        }
      }
    }
```

But when I checked it on UI side, Swagger shows me Response Class and Response Messages with 200 success part displayed in Response Class, not in Response Messages. I want to show both status along with their Model in Response Messages and remove Response Class. How can I do that? Please help me.